# Setting global options in modern CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags

I am using cmake to build my library, which includes a subdirectory for google-test (submodule). As part of my CI pipeline, I am running msan (clang memory sanitizer), which requires me to build the entire project (including google test) with a few special options (`-fsanitize=memory -stdlib=libc++ -L/path/to/libc++/lib -I/path/to/libc++/include` ...).

Right now, I am simply using `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` and a global `include_directories` to set all lib/include paths. However, this goes against "modern cmake" guidelines. Is that an appropriate use of global variables, or is there another way to make it work properly using targets? I can do it for my library, but then it does not propagate to google-test and I get link errors.

Comment: `add_compile_options` adds options to current project and all subdirectores. How is google-test added in your project? I imagine there is one "root" CMakeLists.txt that does add_subdirectory(google-test) and add_subdirectory(your_project), doesn't it look like this?

Comment: Yes that's correct. However, this is just like using my global variables, bypassing targets and all. Most people suggest to stay away from these global setters (same for include_directories). Is that an exception to the rule, or did I miss something?

Comment: I think this is just the case of appropriate usage of a global variable. The same as `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` sets `-g -Og` for all(!) files, you doing the same. I could even see `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=msanitize`.

Answer (score 0):

The modern cmake usages for the options you are looking for are [add_compile_options()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_compile_options.html) as well as [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) where you can specify public and private includes for the specified target project.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can add compile options and include directories to my library, but I would also need to do it to google-test, which is my problem here. I do not want to modify google-test's CMakeLists.txt file, and setting google's options from my library's CMakeLists does not look much better to me either.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you wanna compile gtest with some specific compiler options as well?

Comment: Yes, exactly. the entire codebase must be compiled using libc++ and msan for it to work (https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/MemorySanitizerLibcxxHowTo)

Comment: I guess you have to build gtest with their not-so-modern cmake script and then build your code with modern cmake.. you need not build gtest everytime you build your code base.. I would recommend the submodule method in this article as well: https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/testing/googletest.html

Comment: I think OP refers to [this guideline](https://github.com/boost-cmake/bcm/wiki/Cmake-best-practices-and-guidelines#target_compile_options) and it says: `Avoid the *add_compile_options()* command.`

Comment: It also says avoid adding options to compile_flags.. I think its a recommendation in order to prevent the user from adding unnecessary compiler flags.. I dont think it is a recommendation against the usage of the provided cmake option.. : )